# Reading Dashboard with the metadata API not working

Tags: reporting, metadata-api, jsforce

I'm trying to read all of the dashboards in a particular folder with the Metadata API.  I'm using jsforce `connection.metadata.readSync`.

The dashboards all appear similar in the UI, and most of them let me read them with the metadata API.  But one of them is missing the section `dashboardGridLayout`, which is of course where the most important information is.

Any idea why the metadata API would not be pulling dashboardGridLayout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reports in the Dashboard was in a private folder.  Once I moved the report to the same folder as all of the other reports, I was able to pull the metadata.